# Query latest data from huge amount of data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Part of my work is QA for data in some remote SQL servers. And I'm only granted to query data.

Everyday, I have to execute some SQL scripts to query data in each column of every table. These tables are holding data collected by some programs day by day. I only need to query data in the latest week. Since the huge amount of data and not all fields are indexed, some of my query always timeout.

Does anyone have any good idea to help me out? Really appreciate.

Comment: You might be out of luck here - outside of a limited range of queries, SQL Server will pull all of the data from the remote server, and then apply the filter (WHERE) locally. I can't remember how much this is documented though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a where Clause on your query which filters out data for the last week only 
and

Request for an index  on all columns u want to access...

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, except the index... I'm asked to query all the fields, such like counting number of the empty string or NULL values of each column, but is it okay to create index on all the fields?

Comment: you should add an index on only those fields which you are using in your 'where' clause...
Review each of your queries...pull out everything in your where clause and create a non clustered index on that...
If you are joining multiple tables..ur join condition fields accessed need an index preferably clustered.

Comment: Thanks!I think there is no better way to deal with that. I'm planning to ask my client's DBA to add index for those fields.

Answer (score 0):

use limit and then order by date time descended.

```
SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But I'm afraid that 'LIMIT' doesn't work in SQLServer 2005.